# Jenkins email artifact for each build

Tags: android, jenkins

I am using Jenkins to build my Android Applications. Once the artifact has been created i want the apk to be email to a set of users. I am already aware of Testflight etc but i just need Jenkins to email the signed apk to a set of users. How can i do this ?

Kind Regards

Comment: no not yet. The plugin is fine, but hav not been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 12):

I did the exact same thing,
So first install the **Email Extension Plugin** for jenkins 
then **configure** the job, **add post-build action** --> **Editable email notification**
fill the Project Recipient List etc.. 
and there's the **Attachments** section where you can type the **relative address of the apk** file 
(the base directory is the **workspace's** root directory)

And finally you have to setup the trigger (**add trigger**) and choose the **success** 'cos you dont have the apk at the specified path if the build was unsuccessful.

Comment: I am not able to receive apk through mail......getting this : Malware was detected in one or more attachments included with this email message. Action: All attachments have been removed. android-release-signed.apk

Comment: Jenkins is sending the apk correctly, but your mail system is filtering out the attachment as suspicious. You might want to tweak the filters or embed the apk in a less suspicious format (zip?).

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is the [Email Ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin). It has options for attaching artifacts from the build.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install  Email Ext plugin.After installing follow this step.

- Click the ‘Add post-build action’ drop-down and select the ‘Editable Email Notification’ option.
- In Project Recipient List , This is a comma separated list (optional whitespace after commas) of email addresses that should receive emails. May contain references to build parameters. To CC or BCC someone instead of putting them in the To list, add cc: or bcc: before the email address (e.g., cc:someone@example.com, bcc:bob@example.com).
- You can define Default Subject and Default Content as per your project requirement.
- In Attachments field, you have to give the path of your binary file (i.e path of your .APK file like app/build/outputs/apk/**/*.apk)

[image]

- Now click on Advanced Settings at bottom right corner.
- Click on Add trigger and select Success trigger.
  [image]
- Click on Add drop down from the success trigger  and select Recipient List  option.
- Now Apply and save the Configuration. You can send the apk in email to each user which is selected in recipient.

That's how you can send the apk in email.Thank you.